# Eclipse builder producing indexoutofbounds exception

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, metadata

**Read**:  This is not my code that is producing the exception. This is purely the builder that is making this error. This is not a duplicate of any question that is related to the indexoutofbounds exception as it pertains to written code.

I'm using the most recent version of eclipse, and when I try to build any project in my workspace, I get the  following error

```
'Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project '[project]'.
offset 9673, count -7399, length 13677'
```

Looking into the log yields the full stacktrace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 0 2020-11-13 22:54:50.333
!MESSAGE Error in JDT Core during reconcile
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset 9673, count -7399, length 13677
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.makeConsistent(CompilationUnit.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset 9673, count -7399, length 13677
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsOffCount(String.java:3304)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.rangeCheck(String.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.disambiguatedToken(Scanner.java:5491)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken(Scanner.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.LexStream.readTokenFromScanner(LexStream.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.LexStream.token(LexStream.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.LexStream.kind(LexStream.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.DiagnoseParser.diagnoseParse(DiagnoseParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.reportSyntaxErrors(Parser.java:14010)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12843)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12902)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.parseStatements(ConstructorDeclaration.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.parseMethods(TypeDeclaration.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.getMethodBodies(Parser.java:11825)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceRefElement.generateInfos(SourceRefElement.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.find(SearchableEnvironment.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findType(SearchableEnvironment.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.fromSplitPackageOrOracle(LookupEnvironment.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.lambda$1(LookupEnvironment.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForTypeFromModules(LookupEnvironment.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:3175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:1257)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.internalFaultInTypeForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:272)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset 9673, count -7399, length 13677
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsOffCount(String.java:3304)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.rangeCheck(String.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.disambiguatedToken(Scanner.java:5491)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken(Scanner.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.LexStream.readTokenFromScanner(LexStream.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.LexStream.token(LexStream.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.LexStream.kind(LexStream.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose.DiagnoseParser.diagnoseParse(DiagnoseParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.reportSyntaxErrors(Parser.java:14010)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12843)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12902)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.parseStatements(ConstructorDeclaration.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.parseMethods(TypeDeclaration.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.getMethodBodies(Parser.java:11825)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceRefElement.generateInfos(SourceRefElement.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.find(SearchableEnvironment.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findType(SearchableEnvironment.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.fromSplitPackageOrOracle(LookupEnvironment.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.lambda$1(LookupEnvironment.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForTypeFromModules(LookupEnvironment.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:3175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:1257)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.internalFaultInTypeForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.makeConsistent(CompilationUnit.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:210)
```

What is causing this error? If I was to guess, it is the metadata of the workspace or files not matching up with the actual files, however there is not enough information online to confirm this.

I have tried deleting all workspace metadata, clearing all eclipse configuration files, running eclipse with -clean, and re-installing my JDK (JDK 11). None of these attempts have changed or removed the error.

How do I remove this error and allow eclipse to build again?

Comment: The first rule of weird error messages is to Google "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException jdt compiler"  -- you'll find a number of Eclipse bugs listed, enough that I'll leave it to you to figure out which one applies in your case.

Comment: @JimGarrison There are no results for this error type with the first line of the stack trace to match.

Comment: The final 'caused by' part of the stack trace is the real problem. This appears to be Eclipse bug [567319](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567319) or one of the many duplicates. A problem introduced in 4.17 (2020-09) and fixed in 4.18 (2020-12)